# Where can I read about the technical implementation of web databases in Google Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, local-storage, web-storage

I've read up on the standards regarding [WebSQL](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/), [IndexedDB](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/), and [localStorage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/), but where can I read up on how a specific browser (Google Chrome in this instance) actually implements these features?

I know I could read source code from Chromium, but I assumed there would be some introduction/documentation type articles put out by the teams that built the browsers on the subject. I've been searching for a while and haven't found anything.

Comment: I've tried googling several things and haven't had any luck. So I thought someone might know here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean "actually implements" as in "what C++ code is written to make magical HTML5 things happen", then the code really is the best you can do. There are a variety of design documents floating around ([like this old one for IndexedDB](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/indexeddb)) that the teams sometimes keep up to date, but the code itself is the best source for implementation details. Sifting through the tests ([for IndexedDB, for example](https://code.google.com/codesearch#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/chrome/test/data/indexeddb/)) is a good way to get started. Further discussion of implementation details takes place on [chromium-dev](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-dev/) and [webkit-dev](https://lists.webkit.org/pipermail/webkit-dev/), searching those lists for tidbits is another good source of information.

If, on the other hand, you meant "actually implements" as in "what bits of HTML5 can I use in browser X", then [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/) is probably your best bet for up-to-date feature compatibility tables.